# Tell nvcc to execute a loop's iterations in SIMD mode

Tags: cuda, openmp

In OpenMP there is a way in which the programmer can hint to the compiler that the body of a loop can be vectorized. Is there something similar in CUDA C? Can we tell nvcc to use vector instructions when translating body of a loop? The code is supposed to be executed by thread processors which are SIMD, so that might be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something similar in CUDA C? Can we tell nvcc to use vector instructions when translating body of a loop?

CUDA C is not a translation engine in the same way that OpenMP pragmas result in translation of code.

For the most part, CUDA GPUs have no vector instructions (excepting [SIMD intrinsics](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD) and the corresponding [PTX SIMD Video instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#video-instructions)). Typically, "vectorization" on a GPU is achieved via the [SIMT mechanism](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture).

A CUDA GPU thread processor is not SIMD.  It is a single threaded single-data processor.  SIMD/SIMT comes about by aggregation of adjacent threads into warps.

You may wish to review one of the CUDA whitepapers, such as the [Fermi whitepaper](http://www.nvidia.com/content/pdf/fermi_white_papers/nvidiafermicomputearchitecturewhitepaper.pdf) e.g. page 7, which gives an overview of GPU thread execution.

Answer (score 0):

CUDA C is not a translation engine but OpenACC is, it's OpenMP for accelerators like graphic cards, this will really answer your question:
https://developer.nvidia.com/openacc